# Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator error

Tags: flutter, dart

when I want to do page navigation with flutter, "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator." I get an error. My codes are like this.
..................................................................................................................................................................................

```
void main() => runApp(const Reservation());

class Reservation extends StatefulWidget {
  const Reservation({super.key, });





  @override
  State<Reservation> createState() => _ReservationState();
}


class _ReservationState extends State<Reservation> {

  TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    username.text = "";
    password.text = "";
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Paynasoft",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(

        appBar:  AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          title: Image.asset('image/6.png', fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 32,),

        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
                children: [

                  Container(

                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
                      child: Image.asset('image/paynasoft.png', fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 180,)),

                  TextField(
                      controller: username,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Username",
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.people),
                        border: myinputborder(),
                        enabledBorder: myinputborder(),
                        focusedBorder: myfocusborder(),

                      )
                  ),
                  Container(height: 20,),
                  TextField(
                    controller: password,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                      labelText: "Password",
                      enabledBorder: myinputborder(),
                      focusedBorder: myfocusborder(),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 350,
                    child:

                    FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      label: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,),),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: () {Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const MobileScreenLayout(),
                        ),
                      );},
                    ),

                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Padding (padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text('I forgot my password?'),
                  ),

                ]),

          ),
        ),

      ),

    );



  }

  OutlineInputBorder myinputborder(){ //return type is OutlineInputBorder
    return OutlineInputBorder( //Outline border type for TextFeild
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color:Colors.green,
          width: 3,
        )
    );
  }

  OutlineInputBorder myfocusborder(){
    return OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color:Colors.green,
          width: 3,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

screen.dart

```
class MobileScreenLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const MobileScreenLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MobileScreenLayout> createState() => _MobileScreenLayoutState();
}

class _MobileScreenLayoutState extends State<MobileScreenLayout> {
  int _page = 0;
  late PageController pageController; // for tabs animation

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pageController.dispose();
  }

  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      _page = page;
    });
  }

  void navigationTapped(int page) {
    //Animating Page
    pageController.jumpToPage(page);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        children: homeScreenItems,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: (_page == 0) ? primaryColor : secondaryColor,
            ),
            label: '',
            backgroundColor: primaryColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: (_page == 1) ? primaryColor : secondaryColor,
              ),
              label: '',
              backgroundColor: primaryColor),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add_circle,
                color: (_page == 2) ? primaryColor : secondaryColor,
              ),
              label: '',
              backgroundColor: primaryColor),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: (_page == 3) ? primaryColor : secondaryColor,
            ),
            label: '',
            backgroundColor: primaryColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: (_page == 4) ? primaryColor : secondaryColor,
            ),
            label: '',
            backgroundColor: primaryColor,
          ),
        ],
        onTap: navigationTapped,
        currentIndex: _page,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are directly navigating from the `MaterialApp` widget you are getting the error. we need to create a new stateful or stateless widget to get this working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Reservation());

class Reservation extends StatefulWidget {
  const Reservation({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<Reservation> createState() => _ReservationState();
}

class _ReservationState extends State<Reservation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Paynasoft',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    username.text = '';
    password.text = '';
    super.initState();
  }

  OutlineInputBorder myinputborder() {
    //return type is OutlineInputBorder
    return const OutlineInputBorder(
      //Outline border type for TextFeild
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: 3,
      ),
    );
  }

  OutlineInputBorder myfocusborder() {
    return const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: 3,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: Image.asset(
          'image/6.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          height: 32,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'image/paynasoft.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 180,
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: username,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Username',
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.people),
                  border: myinputborder(),
                  enabledBorder: myinputborder(),
                  focusedBorder: myfocusborder(),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: password,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  enabledBorder: myinputborder(),
                  focusedBorder: myfocusborder(),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 350,
                child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  label: const Text(
                    'Login',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: () {
                     Navigator.push(
                       context,
                       MaterialPageRoute(
                         builder: (context) => const MobileScreenLayout(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('I forgot my password?'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This should solve your problem